# Discrete Mathematics (Need help with examples)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm in need of some help here with my intro to Discrete Mathematics class. My homework is suppose to be more challenging than the book, so it's difficult to find examples within the book. That being said, I posted the first problem to each question, in hopes to getting an example... then I can proceed to doing the rest.

1. Suppose that A and B are sets with |A| = 3 and |B| = 5; both sets are drawn from a universe U with |U| = 11. Determine the possible values for each of the cardinalities below; give examples of the extreme (i.e. maximum and minimum) values.

   (a)     |A ∩ B|.

*(I get that A has 3 unique elements in the set and B has 5. But I do not understand how to find the possible values and extreme)*

2. Let S and T be (finite) sets. For each assertion below, determine whether it is true or false. If it’s true, then explain why; if it’s false, give an example to show that it’s false.

   (a)    P(S ∪ T) = P(S) ∪ P(T).
3. Let P(x) be the open statement “x is thick”, Q(x) be “x has a hard cover”, R(x,y) “x is more expensive than y”, S(x,y) “x is harder to read than y”, and let B be the set of all books. Write the following statements in terms of quantified symbolic logic.

   (a)    Some books have hard covers.
4. Prove each of the following assertions.

   (a)    The sum of any two odd numbers is even.

Thank you for any help. If you do not feel like explaining all of them, I'm happy with whatever examples you can show me.

Comment: For 1a), what do you think is the minimum and maximum number of elements that A and B can have in common?

Comment: For 2a), you need to clarify what does $P(S \cup T)$ mean.

Comment: For 1a) do you see that $A$ and $B$ can, on one hand be disjoint, and, on the other hand, be included one into the other. Conclusion for $|A \cap B|$ ?

Comment: For 3a), saying "Some books have hard covers" is the same as saying "There exists book(s) that have hard covers". So, in quantified symbolic logic, it would be $\exists x \in B, Q(x)$

Comment: @user137481 ohh that makes sense, so maximum number of elements that A AND B can have would be 3. Then I'm assuming minimum would be 0, as it could have no elements that are the same in A and B.

Comment: Yes, min is 0 (i.e. disjoint as mentioned by Jean Marie) and max is 3 (in the case that $A = B$)

Comment: For 4a), let $x$ and $y$ be 2 odd integers. By definition of odd, $x=2m+1$ and $y=2n+1$ for some $m$ and $n$. So, $x+y = 2(m + n + 1)$ is even.

Comment: @user137481 Thank you so much, 1 and 3 are making a lot more sense (I'll need to work a bit on 4 though, as I'm struggling with proofs). If you do not mind me checking one more problem for 3... would 'No books are thick.' look something like this: ~x ∈ B, P(x)

Comment: For "no books", it should be $\sim \exists x \in B, Q(x)$

Comment: For 2, construct two simple sets. (Couple of elements). Calculate the union and finally make 3 simple functions. One bijective, one surjective and one injective. Play around with that little gaggle of items and you should be fine for answering 2